# How can a metric space be expressed as a set of variables?

Tags: metric-spaces

I saw a post on here along the following lines:

> Consider a metric space $(S,D,K)$.

**edit:** The original post said $(X,d)$; not sure if this makes a significant difference.

When a metric space is described as a set of variables, does this just indicate the dimensions of the metric space as well as the ordered set of coordinates which the points in this space will have?  For instance, for a metric space $(X,Y)$, is it just a two-dimensional space in which every point has a coordinate $(X,Y)$ in which $X$ and $Y$ are determined with respect to $(0,0)$?  Or, for any $n$-dimensional metric space, the origin $(0_1,0_2...0_n)$?

Here is the post for reference:
[image]

Here is the link: https://mathoverflow.net/q/312176/128941

Comment: I have no idea what "a metric space $(S,D,K)$" might mean. It might help if you could link to the post where you saw that, Maybe there are some hints in the context.

Comment: By the way, did you pick the euclidean-domain tag because you just liked the sound of it, or did you read the tag description?

Comment: @bof added the original text for reference.  Sorry if me picking the wrong tag bothered you; I’ll take better precaution next time.

Comment: I can't find the weird expression $(S,D,K)$ in the quotation you provided. Is that from a post on this Stack Exchange site? Could you possibly provide a link to the post itself?

Comment: @bof sorry, I didn’t quote it exactly because I couldn’t remember it at the time of posting.  I figured the exactly variables wouldn’t matter, because they are, well, variables.  This is a post from MathOverflow.  I will grab the link as soon as I can.

Comment: It doesn't matter too much what letters you use for the variables, but changing the **number** of variables makes quite a difference. I don't know what definition of "metric space" you've learned, but normally [metric space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_space) is a pair $(X,d)$ where $X$ is a set of points and $d$ is a distance function which is required to satisfy certain conditions.

Answer (score 1):

It could be **Product Metric** if S, D, K do not share the same metric.
So the metric of the set $(S,D,K)$ is,

$d(x,y) = ||(d_S(x_S,y_S), d_D(x_D,y_D), d_K(x_K,y_K))||$

I've read a text in the past, which described a union of sets using that notation. I guess it will depend on whether a metric is given to you.

Comment: Hi, I was looking back at my old posts and found this question. It was total gibberish and I'd like to delete it. Could you remove your answer so that I can do so (if that is OK with you)?